# Searching for a Teenage Horror book series from the 90s

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, horror

I have been searching for a book series I used to read in the 90s.

It was a young adult/teenage horror series and in every book it started with a sleepover, then one of the girls would tell the story - The individual stories I remember are

- one about a headless horseman
- one set in a ballroom
- one set on a boat
- and one set in a  windmill.

  Does anyone have any idea which books these could be? It's driving me mad!

Comment: Goosebumps? These are the first that come to mind.

Comment: I remember one of the stories being about some sort of cursed hand or claw and another story about a chandelier falling on one of the girl's boyfriends. I wonder if they are the same series?

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for the *Creepover* series?
https://www.goodreads.com/series/110223-you-re-invited-to-a-creepover

According to the summary:

> Go to sleep...if you dare, because you're invited to a creepover! This new middle-grade horror series combines two things that kids love--sleepovers and scary stories.
>   Each book in the series revolves around a sleep over. On the back of each book is a Creep-o-Meter, a gauge, to show how scary each story is. This meter rates 1-5 (5 being the scariest).

Although it sounds like a sleepover is part of the story, not that a sleepover is used to begin a story-within-a-story.

Answer (score 2):

I think I recognise these books you are talking about - could it be Sleepover by Sharon Siamon? https://www.goodreads.com/series/52932-sleepover

The series sounds really familiar :)